# Allow closing/flagging the parent question of answers from review panel

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close, review

When reviewing answers, you sometimes come across answers which are opinionated or just links. This prompts you to look at the question to see what it is *asking* for, because obviously a question that actually asks for opinions and links can be closed as not constructive, and thus no action would need to be taken on the answer itself. However, this involves leaving the review panel because the vote to close and flag options are not available under the question when you pull the tab down to view more of the question.

This actually addresses multiple concerns/annoyances at once:

1. The pull down tab is really annoying. Would it be possible to just get a couple lines of the question at the top with an "expand question" link to view the full question (pull the tab all the way down). Also make it so the tab can't be pulled down farther than the question content goes.
2. Include the normal options for the question to link, vote to close, flag, delete, etc.
3. Have votes to close, flags, votes to delete count towards your actioned posts for the review stats. After all, that first/late answer did *directly* cause you to take action on the question it was under.

Comment: Yeah, why not just add all of the functionality from *the entire site* to the review panel?