# Late answers in the /review queue (#1) - inline flag or vote on the _question_

Tags: feature-request, review

[In this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592569/how-to-show-data-in-a-gridview-by-c-sharp-using-an-sql-server-database), I shouldn't need to vote down or flag the answer, because the question itself is a dog.

[image]

Users should be allowed to also enable the "I'm done" button by down voting, close voting or flagging the **question** rather than directly taking action on the answer.

Currently, I have to click on the question's title, close or down vote it in the new tab, then go back to the review page, and click "Not sure" to continue on my adventure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is voting removed from new review system?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system)

Comment: @YannisRizos - nope. Not a duplicate of that. That request was for voting in general (which is now allowed on some queues) this is for voting/closing/flagging on the **question** when reviewing an **answer**.

Comment: @YannisRizos I'm not sure why that question didn't show up in my search. In any case Shog's answer seems to indicate that voting has been enabled when it hasn't?

Comment: @slugster Voting has been enabled in answers in the Late Answers queue, you are asking about voting in the question.

Comment: @ChrisF At first read I though it sufficiently explained why review doesn't really focus on voting, and that made it a dupe, but on second read, that was a poor close vote.

Comment: Related question from old review panel interface: [Allow closing/flagging the parent question of answers from review panel](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115898/allow-closing-flagging-the-parent-question-of-answers-from-review-panel)

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that in the situation where you have an answer under review against a poor question that you should do two things -

1. Firstly vote/comment on the answer itself as part of the review process. That answerer deserves your feedback regardless of whether they've answered a good *or* a bad question. Even if that question gets deleted eventually the answerer will still be able to see their answer and comments associated to it (as far as I recall anyway).
2. Secondly go to the question and vote/comment on that one too.

It is possible to have very good answers against very poor questions. That is why the [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) badge exists.

Comment: I agree with your last point, I have no issue with up voting excellent answers. The issue is that I have to leave the page to action the question, and in this case I would rather action the question than the answer (don't forget that there could be several bad answers on the same question). Once action has been started on a question other sub 10K users can then assist, while you have to be [over 20K](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) to directly action an answer (and that action is quite limited).

Comment: This is the correct answer. There are all sorts of things you might want to do outside the context of the review screen - heck, other *answers* maybe could use some attention too. Just because you found out about it from /review doesn't mean you have to stay there.