# What to do with late answers to bad questions?

Tags: discussion, review

The review queue just presented me with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/2746050).

Now, the question strikes me as 'opinion-based'. And it really doesn't help to add another opinionated answer. However, the question is out there, not closed, and the answer isn't spam or incoherent.

I wish that the late answer queue had buttons to do things like vote to close or downvote the question.

Comment: I think I agree there; often those answers are at least OK-ish, insofar as they are responses to the question being asked. It happens enough that a 'bad' answer highlights a bad question that maybe it's worth considering some sort of UI to link actions there... hmmm...

Comment: This should go on the question in question but "is this language oo" isn't really opinion based. Arguments go in both ways, but they will be backed by facts (the majority of the function library is c-style functions (eg string funcs, not oo), but the PHP team is making steps to encourage oo programming within php (eg mysqli class))

Comment: That said, after reading some of the answers, I can see how it _resulted_ in an unfortunately polarized debate, with a lot of people denying pretty obvious facts about the language there.

Comment: @bobobobo "is this language oo" is definitely opinion based. If the OP had asked "does this language support the following OOP paradigms: foo, bar, quux", then that would have inspired answers focusing on verifiable facts. As it stands, you just have quibbling about how object oriented something needs to be **fully** or **truly** object oriented, which doesn't really achieve anything.

Comment: Only responding to your final sentence: While you can't do anything in the queue itself, I frequently find myself right-clicking the question and opening it in a new tab to get a broader view of the question and it's answers - especially with late answers: Is the answer adding anything not already answered, etc. And voting on the question itself, if required.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer isn't spam or incoherent, the only thing you can do is downvote/flag the original question.

> Now, the question strikes me as 'opinion-based'. And it really doesn't help to add another opinionated answer.

That's *exactly* why opinion-based questions are a no-no, because they breed bad answers.

The [question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/2746050) is a bit on the philosophical side, IMHO off-topic but I  [could be wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) since PHP can be described as

> software tools commonly used by programmers

The question here is `is a programming language a programmer's tool?` This might be a good question for [a certain site](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) but the original question is off-topic depending on your interpretation of the FAQ. My recommendation would be to flag the question and let it take its course from there.

In regards to your second question, I agree that being able to vote up/down during reviews would be a very nice feature to have. I wonder why we are unable to do so however.

---

EDIT: Apparently there [used to be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158418/231732) a vote up feature during review but has since [been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158789/231732). Any Pepperidge Farms among us who know exactly how it used to work, please point me to a screenshot or equivalent.

Comment: *"but I could be wrong since PHP can be described as software tools commonly used by programmers"* The mere fact that the question is about a programming language doesn't make it suitable for the site. The main question is not about whether PHP supports certain OOP paradigms, but about whether it supports them enough (in an answerer's opinion) to qualify for the "object-oriented" label. That is a subjective question.

Comment: That's why I wanted to suggest moving it to Programmers.SE but I thought they wouldn't want it there. It is curious however how it got 11 upvotes.

Comment: Vote on a question don't indicate if the question is on topic or not.

Answer (score 0):

> the answer isn't spam or incoherent

You are right, but the answer isn't a good productive one either, so the correct course of action is to down vote it.

> Now, the question strikes me as 'opinion-based'

I would have to disagree with this. It's badly asked and needs a tidy up, but I believe this one could still be answered definitively, including references to reputable sources. Of course this doesn't stop people tendering opinion based answers, but these should be treated in the appropriate way depending on their quality. This particular question is crying out for some recent CompSci grad to offer a detailed answer proving it one way or another.

> I wish that the late answer queue had buttons to do things like vote to close or downvote the question

This statement/wish is an exact duplicate: [Late answers in the /review queue (#1) - inline flag or vote on the *question*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148121/146015)