# Why do I have to make work for mods by flagging 'not an answer' in the late answer queue?

Tags: feature-request, review, late-answers, trusted-user

Sometimes late answers are crap. That's why we have a late answer queue. For 'plain vanilla crap', I downvote. That's nice. However, extra-special (not really an answer) crap should be deleted.

OK, I have 20K, I can vote to delete. Except that, I can't vote to delete from the review queue. I can, however, annoy the diamonds by flagging 'not an answer'.

One of my minor goals in life is to avoid <del>interactions with</del> annoying the diamonds. So, I've taken to slogging through the extra clicks to open up the question so that I can cast a delete vote on the answer. Please consider adding a review button that says, 'downvote and vote to delete if possible' visible to us folks with the required privilege.

Two clarifications:

1. This question is purely about 'late answers'. Not about 'low quality'.
2. Flagging 'very low quality', and then seeing it again in the low quality queue, is not less work than opening it up to delete it.

Comment: *possible* duplicate of [Late answers in the /review queue (#1) - inline flag or vote on the \_question\_](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148121/late-answers-in-the-review-queue-1-inline-flag-or-vote-on-the-question)

Comment: You can't delete an answer till it is negatively scored. Are you asking for a change to that - i.e. capability to delete before it goes negative?

Comment: @slugster That is not technically true, not from the review queue.

Comment: @tchrist The 'delete' I mean (and I presume Rosinante means the same one) is the delete option that comes with 20K+ rep, not the delete button you see at the top right.

Comment: @slugster From the Review queue, you can cast an actual delete vote on answers with any non-positive total number of votes.

Comment: @tchrist but not if it's zero when I get there and -1 after I vote. This is the case I'm on about.

Comment: I think that’s untrue. At least, it is for me. I can delete things with a 0 vote from the review queue. I guess I misunderstand you.

Comment: @tchrist in the late answer queue? I was sure it was not possible, but maybe I've been inattentive.

Comment: No, in the Low Quality queue. Let me check the other one.

Comment: @tchrist OK, then. That's another queue :-)

Comment: @tchrist I've just tried it and Rosinante is correct (at least when it is your own vote that causes it to go negative, there are no negatively scored ones in the queue at the moment which is part of another question from @Ros).

Comment: Just flag it as NAA and it can be deleted from Low Quality Posts review.

Comment: @3ventic You can't flag something directly from the review queue. Using the 'delete' button effectively casts another flag, but you're limited to just those four button options.

Comment: @slugster yes you can. There's a perfectly effective flag button on answers in the late answer queue.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't worry about that. If you find a true non-answer in the Late Answers queue, feel free to flag it as such. This no longer adds much to the moderator workload.

These flags now feed into the Low Quality Posts review queue, where the community can vote on whether or not such a post should be deleted. Almost all of them no longer even wind up being seen by a moderator, and the community voting seems to be working very well from what I can tell.

Even when we still acted on these, they were usually some of the easiest flags to make a call on, so they only became a burden when people would go on flagging sprees for things that actually were answers.

The workflow on this seems to make sense to me as it stands. Late Answers and First Posts are our first line of defense against spam and non-answers, so reviewers first sort through those and label the items that need to be acted on. Spam gets handled by moderators (and we are the only ones with the tools to destroy spammers and their associated accounts, so we gladly take these on).

Potential non-answers get handed off to the Low Quality Posts review queue, which is sort of a second level of quality assessment. Posts there require multiple reviews, and unanimous deletion votes, even from low-rep users, lead to the removal of posts from that queue. As I said, this looks to be handled well by the community so far, and we only get flags for borderline or anomalous cases in that queue.

Maybe I could see having that first "not an answer" flag from the First Posts or Late Answers also automatically cast a delete vote on your behalf in the Low Quality Posts queue, but a developer with better access to the stats might need to weigh in on the potential for abuse there.